# Parsing html in python 3.5 returns strange type

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, urllib

I am running python 3.5 and am trying to pull BINGO data from this web page and I am having some problems. When i split the html response i keep getting the letter b before my list of strings and its making it impossible to check against. I have checked the html output and its of class bytes which i am not familiar with. Why is this b preceding all my strings and second how else can I parse a html page more cleanly.

```
 import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.executiveadministrator.com/cgi-local/inoutPROhosted4/inoutPRO.pl?refresh=1&ID=AFTCO') as response:
   html = response.read()

htmllist = html.split()

print(htmllist)
for i in htmllist:
    #if i == 'BINGO':
    print(i)
```

example output:b'class="colorlinkbody">Renew' b'Board' b'Contract
' b'Copyright' b'1996-2013' b''

Comment: because response.read returns `bytes` no longer `str`. use `encode()`

Answer (score 0):

Since `response.read()` returns `bytes` no longer `str` as mentioned in comments, if you need to get the string value from a bytes object, you have to call the `decode(encoding)` method on the bytes object. Making your print functions:

```
for i in htmllist:
    print(i.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: thanks this seems like a clunky way of getting a list of strings out of html. is there a better way? meaning something other that urllib.request? i am on a windows platform if that matters.

Comment: depends on what you want to do with them, but you should probably look more at html parsing libs like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup` aka `bs4`